# How to repeat a function and make it re run every time in a variable without copying and pasting?

Tags: python

Say this is my code, how do I make random.choice(string.ascii_letters) occur thrice   without copying and pasting it thrice?

```
import random
import string    
test = random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use loop in your existing code :

```
import random
import string
test = ''
for i in range(3):
    test += random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
```

if you want to sure about new value every time then you have to check previous generated value:

```
test = ''
dct = {}
for i in range(3):
    while True:
        c = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        if c not in dct:
            test += c
            dct[c] = 1
            break
```

Comment: Whoops. Editted my question to remove the needing a new value every time.

Comment: then just use the loop like first part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

The method of adding to the same string is quadratic in the size of the loop.  One simple and fast way to do it is using `string.join` and comprehension:

```py
import random
import string
test = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(3))
```

An even simpler, and probably faster solution is to use a different function overall:

```py
import random
import string
''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

import random
import string
test=''
for _ in range(3):
    test += random.choice(string.ascii_letters)

print(test)